# How to make a permutation cycle in 2D array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation, cycle

[image: Here's a picture for better understanding]

A cycle of a permutation is a subset of the elements that replace one another in sequence, until the last element is replaced by the first. At this point i got dynamical 2D array with two rows and "user input cols", which values are also inserted from the user. I need to make a permutation cycles from this array. 
Sorry if i did anything wrong, it's just my first ever post here :).
I tried this, but it is not working properly:

````
    // First element in the array//
    int startingElement = arr[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {

        // If first element in second row is not like the first element in first row we will print ‘(’ and also elements [0][0] and [1][0] //
        if (arr[0][i] != arr[1][i]) {
            cout << "(" << arr[0][i] << " " << arr[1][i];

            int positionOfSecondRowElementInFirstRow = 0;

            for (int firstRowElementIndex = 0; firstRowElementIndex < cols; firstRowElementIndex++) {

                // With this 'if' we will find in which colon(index) in first row we have the element from the second row //
                if (arr[0][firstRowElementIndex] == arr[1][i]) {
                    positionOfSecondRowElementInFirstRow = firstRowElementIndex;
                }
            }

            // This ‘if’ will check if element in first row is equal to out strating element. If it is the program will print ‘)’//
            if (arr[1][positionOfSecondRowElementInFirstRow] == startingElement) {
                cout << ")";

            }
        }

        // Else the program will print the element(this is working when we have fixed points)//
        else {
            cout << "(" << arr[0][i] << ")";
        }
    }

    return true;
} ```
````

Comment: "it is not working properly": please elaborate.

Comment: I don't really know how to improve it and why its  not working properly: example:x   : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, f(x): {2, 1, 5, 4, 3}. , the output is: (1 2)(2 1(3 5(4)(5 3

Comment: If you want to add relevant info to your question (upon request), please, [edit] and modify your question (instead of giving additional info in comments). In general, it couldn't hurt to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You could simplify your code by not having two rows. Since the first row is just natural numbers from 0 to n, you could simply store a single (second) row and treat the first row as indices into that one. So you would effectively create a lookup-table of input elements and output elements.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot fix your given code. It is rather wrong. I checked with the debugger, but no success. Also the design, the algorithm seems to be wrong.

Therefore I created a complete new solution for you.

The secret is to select the correct container type. I use 2. For a cyle, I use a `std::unordered_set`. This can contain only unique elements. With that, an infinite cycle will be prevented. For example: 0,1,3,0,1,3,0,1,3 . . .  is not possible, because each digit can only be once in the container. That will stop our way through the permutations. As soon as we see a number that is already in a cycle, we stop.

All found cycles will be stored in the second container type: A `std::set`. The `std::set` can also contain only unique values and, the values are ordered. Because we store complex data in the `std::set`, we create a custom comparator for it. We need to take care that the `std::set` will not contain 2 double entries. And double would be in our case also 0,1,3 and 1,3,0. In our custom comparator, we will first copy the 2 sets into a `std::vector` and sort the `std::vector`s. This will make 1,3,0 to 0,1,3. Then we can easily detect doubles.

Please note:

I do always only store a value from the first permutation in the cycle. The 2nd is used as helper, to find the index of the next value to evaluate.

Please see the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

// Make reading easier and define some alies names
using MyType = int;
using Cycle = std::unordered_set<MyType>;
using Permutation = std::vector<MyType>;
using Permutations = std::vector<Permutation>;

// We do not want to have double results. 
// A double cyle is also a Cycle with elements in different order
// So define custom comparator functor for our resulting set
struct Comparator {
    bool operator () (const Cycle& lhs, const Cycle& rhs) const {
        // Convert the unordered_sets to vectors
        std::vector<MyType> v1(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
        std::vector<MyType> v2(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
        // Sort them 
        std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
        // Compare them
        return v1 < v2;
    }
};
// Resulting cycles
using Cycles = std::set<Cycle, Comparator>;

int main() {

    // The source data
    Permutations perms2 = {
        {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
        {1,3,7,0,4,8,2,6,5} };

    // Lamda to find the index of a given number in the first permutation
    auto findPos = [&perms2](const MyType& m) {return std::distance(perms2[0].begin(), std::find(perms2[0].begin(), perms2[0].end(), m)); };

    // Here we will store our resulting set of cycles
    Cycles resultingCycles{};

    // Go through all single elements of the first permutation
    for (size_t currentColumn = 0U; currentColumn < perms2[0].size(); ++currentColumn) {

        // This is a temporary for a cycle that we found in this loop
        Cycle trialCycle{};

        // First value to start with
        size_t startColumn = currentColumn;

        // Follow the complete path through the 2 permutations
        for (bool insertResult{ true }; insertResult; ) {

            // Insert found element from the first permutation in the current cycle
            const auto& [newElement, insertOk] = trialCycle.insert(perms2[0][startColumn]);
            // Find the index of the element under the first value (from the 2nd permutation)
            startColumn = findPos(perms2[1][startColumn]);
            // Check if we should continue (Could we inster a further element in our current cycle)
            insertResult = insertOk;
        }

        // We will only consider cycles with a length > 1
        if (trialCycle.size() > 1) {
            // Store the current temporary cycle as an additional result.
            resultingCycles.insert(trialCycle);
        }
    }


    // Simple output
    std::cout << "\n\nFound Cycles:\n\n";
    // Go through all found cycles
    for (const Cycle& c : resultingCycles) {
        // Print an opening brace
        std::cout << "(";
        // Handle the comma delimiter
        std::string delimiter{};

        // Print all integer values of the cycle
        for (const MyType& m : c) {
            std::cout << delimiter << m;
            delimiter = ",";
        }
        std::cout << ")";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```